# String.fromCodePoint() won't work in IE and tab key won't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the code like this, which won't work in IE 10 or Firefox 43:

```
app.directive('limitChars', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (_scope, _element) {
            var allowedChars = /[a-z0-9, ]/;

            _element.on("keypress", function (e) {
                var key = String.fromCodePoint(e.which).toLowerCase();

                if (!allowedChars.test(key) && e.which != 13 && e.which != 8) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

In IE 10, I got "Object doesn't support property or method `fomCodePoint`" error.

In Firefox 43, the "tab" key won't work.

In Chrome, everything works fine.

Anyone knows why? Thanks.

**Update:**

`formCharCode()` seems to work in IE now. But the tab key still won't work in Firefox.

Comment: `fomCodePoint` is newer, you can use `fromCharCode` in older browsers

Comment: The error message explains all in IE. In FF I suppose the default action of TAB might shadow your handler, you've to prevent the default action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use both `e.keyCode` and `e.which`. Below works in all browsers:

```
app.directive('limitChars', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(_scope,_element) {
                var allowedChars = /[a-z0-9, ]/;

                _element.on("keypress",function(e){
                    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

                    var key = String.fromCharCode(keyCode).toLowerCase();

                    if (!allowedChars.test(key) && keyCode != 8 && keyCode != 9 && keyCode != 13 && keyCode != 16) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```